# Cloud Run for Anthos: You don't have any clusters with Cloud Run for Anthos enabled

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos, google-anthos-service-mesh

I'm stuck trying to create a Cloud Run for Anthos service in my organization's GCP project. I'm not very experienced in GKE creation or GCP infra, but I'm noticing some peculiar things after my setup. For context, I want to use Cloud Run for Anthos with GPUs for my deep learning models. Steps followed include:

1. Create a standard GKE cluster (named `cluster-classifier-app-1`) (testing as a public cluster) with 3 e2-standard-4 nodes (8vCPUs is the minimum for the Service Mesh based on the docs) [link](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/v1.10/docs/scripted-install/asm-onboarding#requirements).
2. Enable Service Mesh during Setup. (This registers the cluster with the Anthos Fleet)
3. I head over to the `Cloud Run for Anthos` menu and I see a `You don't have any clusters with Cloud Run for Anthos enabled.` message before I can create a service.

Some screenshots:

1. [Cluster registered with Fleet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXRU0.png)
2. [Cluster Details as viewed in Anthos `Clusters` Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/099DM.png) (Notice the `Cloud Run for Anthos: Unable to connect to cluster` message on the top, but the `Cloud Run for Anthos` item under `Cluster Features` says enabled)
3. [Services page in Cloud Run Anthos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a69uP.png) (Notice the error message `Missing data from clusters`)
4. [Create Service Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUV07.png) (You don't have any clusters with Cloud Run for Anthos enabled.)

Peculiarities:

1. [Viewing the cluster details on the Kubernetes Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjUub.png) Displays `Cloud Run for Anthos` as disabled although it says enabled in Screenshot 2.
2. In the Anthos `Features` tab - `Cloud Run for Anthos` displays `Enabled` and `The API appdevelopmentexperience.googleapis.com is not enabled for project` even though it is.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z08Ig.png)

I'm new to this and I've gone over relevant docs multiple times. I'd appreciate some help and happy to provide any details if necessary.

Comment: I have the same problem; did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it was due to my cluster being autopilot. Apparently, you cannot edit Cloud Run enable/disable for these.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . This command helped. I think this enables cloud run on the cluster we created.

```
gcloud container hub cloudrun apply --gke-cluster=asia-southeast1/my-anthos-cluster-name
```

Saw it in [this](https://codersociety.com/blog/articles/running-serverless-pods-on-cloud-run-for-anthos) website.